# Quartz Scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am currently working on Quartz Scheduler (version 1.4.2). I am trying to code scheduler in such a way so that I can set Repeat Interval duration after starting the scheduler. I tried many ways to do it but its not working. Can anyone tell me how can we adjust the Repeat Interval Duration during runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to unschedule the current job first, then reschedule it with the new interval value.  Put a form in your GUI to use to set the new interval value at runtime, you can process the rescheduling when the value gets updated.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653556/480579) for an example using CronTrigger.  The details will vary slightly for an Interval job, but it should be enough to get you going.