# Altering Quartz Job Schedule

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm looking into scheduling my application with Quartz, but in all cases, the job trigger seems to be a one-time activity, and changes to the trigger need the application to be re-deployed to take effect.
Is there any way I can have the job trigger check for changes to the job schedule without having to redeploy the code?
Thanks,

Comment: How do you schedule your jobs (in code)? It's definitely possible to reschedule jobs at runtime.

Comment: Currently, I'm putting the scheduler in the `init` method of my servlet. What I'd like to do is read the CronTrigger from a an external resource bundle at specific intervals an refresh the trigger with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Trap some user-driven event, like updating a text value, for example a cron-string to schedule a job
2. Locate and unschedule/delete the old job and trigger.
3. Schedule the job again, using the new trigger.

   ```
   public static <T> T scheduleCronJob(Class<T> clazz, String cronString, String uid){
       try{            
           if(cronString == null){
               throw new CronStringConfigurationException();
           }

           String jobGroupName = "cronJobsGroup";
           String jobName = "cronJob" + uid;
           String triggerGroupName = "cronTriggers";
           String triggerName = "triggerFor" + uid;

           JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(jobName, jobGroupName, clazz);

           CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(
                   triggerName, triggerGroupName, 
                   jobName, jobGroupName, 
                   cronString);

           JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
           jobDetail.setJobDataMap(jobDataMap);

           getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
       } catch(Exception e){
       // print error message, throw stack trace
       }
       return null;
   }

   public static void reloadCronJob(Class clazz, String cronString, String uid) throws SystemException, ParseException, SchedulerException, 
       CronStringConfigurationException, PortalException{
       // locate the job 
       String jobGroupName = "cronJobs";
       String jobName = "jobFor" + uid;

       if(cronString == null){
           throw new CronStringConfigurationException();
       }

       JobDetail jobDetail = null;
       Class<?> jobClass = null;

       // remove the old job/trigger if it exists
       try{
           jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobName, jobGroupName);
           if(jobDetail != null){
               jobClass = jobDetail.getJobClass();
           }
           scheduler.deleteJob(jobName, jobGroupName);
       } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       if(jobClass == null){
           jobClass = clazz;
       }

       // create a new trigger
       scheduleCronJob(jobClass, expandoColumnName, uid);

       System.out.println("(re)scheduled job " + jobName + " using new cron string " + cronString);
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem is how do you identity the schedule? or you just create a new scheduler? What is the `getScheduler()` in `getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);`?